# Como fazer um mapeamento de imagem ser responsivo?

Tags: html, imagem, maps

```
<img id="Imag" usemap="#Calculadora" width="100%" height="auto" src="Calculadora.png">
            <map name="Calculadora">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="252,953,647,1379" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="746,952,1141,1375" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1258,954,1644,1377" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1752,941" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="252,1469,638,1883" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="746,1465,1132,1879" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1258,1465,1644,1879" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="2156,745,2381,988" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1752,1469,2138,1883" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="252,1976,638,2390" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="746,1980,1132,2394" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1258,1976,1644,2390" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1752,1982,2138,2396" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="252,2482,638,2896" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="746,2484,1132,2898" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1258,2486,1644,2900" shape="rect">
                <area class="mapa" onclick="teste()" coords="1752,2484,2138,2898" shape="rect">
            </map>
```

Como posso fazer com que o mapping dessa imagem se torne responsivo junto da imagem?
Pois do jeito com que o codigo esta escrito, o mapeamento fica inteiramente errado dependendo da resolução do display/tela.

Imagem que estou utilizando: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnMqG.jpg

OBS: Tentei usar porcentagem no lugar de pixeis, mas não funcionou.

Exemplo: A imagem a seguir tem 500px de largura e altura, as coordenadas do quadrado no centro é: 159,159,342,342. Usando porcentagem ficou: 31.80%,31.80%,68.40%,68.40%(Para definir o valor das primeiras porcentagens fiz uma regra de três, 500 estava para 159, tal como 100% estava para x)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E fazendo por esse metodo, não funcionou.

O codigo desse exemplo ficou assim:

```
<img id="Imag" usemap="#Calculadora" width="100%" src="AAAA.jpg">
   <map name="Calculadora">
      <area class="mapa" coords="31.80%,31.80%,68.40%,68.40%" shape="rect">
   </map>
```

Obs2: Se no exemplo a cima eu fizer: `coords="159%,159%,342%,342%"` funciona, mas não fica responsivo, se a imagem tem sua resulução mudada, o link fica no lugar errado.

Comment: Dica https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/

Comment: @hugocsl tentei usar esse site, mas não entendi onde colocar o codigo que ele me disponibilizou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOIIII!**

Para fazer um mapeamento responsivo de uma imagem, utilizei javascript. Ele tinha a função de pegar a resoluçao da imagem(Usei "document.getElementById('Id da imagem').width") e de acordo com a proporção que eu dei em porcentagem, calcular qual seria a cordenada certa para o mapeamento.

Exemplo:

```css
#Mapa
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="Imag" usemap="#QuadradoMap" width="100%" src="Imagem.jpg">
            <map id="Mapa" name='QuadradoMap'>
            </map>
        <script>
      //Aquisição da resolução da imagem
            var largura = document.getElementById('Imag').width;
            var altura = document.getElementById('Imag').height;
      
      //Definição das coordenadas utilizando as devidas proporções
            var cord1 = largura*0.318;
            var cord2 = largura*0.318;
            var cord3 = altura*0.684;
            var cord4 = altura*0.684;
      
      //Junção das coordenadas
            var cordg = "" + cord1 + "," + cord2 + "," + cord3 + "," + cord4 + ""; 

      
      //Criação do elemento area
            var Area = document.createElement("area");

      //Criação dos atributos do elemento area
            var Forma = document.createAttribute("shape");
            Forma.value = "rect";
            var Cord = document.createAttribute("coords");
            Cord.value = cordg ;
            var Classe = document.createAttribute("class");
            Classe.value = "mapa";

      //Atribuição dos atributos
            Area.setAttributeNode(Forma);
            Area.setAttributeNode(Cord);
            Area.setAttributeNode(Classe);
      
      //Adição do elemento area ao elemento Mapa
            document.getElementById("Mapa").appendChild(Area);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

O tamanho original da "Imagem.jpg" era de 500x500 e o mapping original era: 159,159,342,342. Utilizando regra de 3 descobri qual era o percentual de cada coordenada de acordo com o total(500), assim descobri a proporção da imagem para as coordenadas(Nesse exempo: 31,8% e 68,4%).

Vai dar um trabalho para escalar esse codigo, mas foi a unica resposta que consegui encontrar.